# Entity Framework: Establishing relation table in code first TPH hierarchy

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.3

I am setting up a series of relationships between related objects within a TPH system.

```
public abstract class Box
{
    public Box()
    {
        Boxes = new HashSet<Box>();
        Descriptors = new HashSet<Descriptor>();
    }

    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Box> Boxes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Descriptor> Descriptors { get; set; }
}
```

This base class is extended by for instance 3 separate sub classes

```
public class Item: Box
{
    public Sample()
    {
        Events = new HashSet<Event>();
        Phones = new HashSet<Phone>();
    }

    public virtual ICollection<Phone> Phones { get; private set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> Events{ get; private set; }
}

public class Phone : Box {}


public class Event: Box
{
    public Item { get; private set; }
}
```

With TPH it seems to be setting up the relation in the Box table instead of creating an outside relation table to relate the Item, Phone, and Event Objects. I can't find a good example of what the mapping would look like on this.

Comment: It is creating one-to-many self referencing relation - as your model defined. Are you expecting many-to-many relation with junction table?

Comment: Yes, basically, this is only a small part of the actual object graph. THere are lots of types of boxes and relations between them. It just seems to make more sense to store the relations in one place.